# Convert a datetime to time with miliseconds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I got a DataFrame:

```
client    datetime
1       01/02/2020 13:47
2       02/02/2020 23:45
3       03/02/2020 16:22
4       04/02/2020 18:49
5       05/02/2020 11:02
```

and I need two new columns ["time_new"] to display the time in this format ('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] and ["time_ms"] to display ms only:

```
client    datetime           time_new        time_ms
1       01/02/2020 13:47   13:47:11.783      783
2       02/02/2020 23:45   23:45:22.322      322
3       03/02/2020 16:22   16:22:05.122      122
4       04/02/2020 18:49   18:49:03.329      329
5       05/02/2020 11:02   11:02:34.545      545
```

Comment: In source dataframe is no time in second and miliseconds?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to set your expectations. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Answer (score 0):

For extract custom format with times and miliseconds use:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['time_new'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
df['time_ms'] = df['datetime'].dt.microsecond // 1000

#in source df are 0 second and milisecond, so output like this
print (df)
   client            datetime      time_new  time_ms
0       1 2020-01-02 13:47:00  13:47:00.000        0
1       2 2020-02-02 23:45:00  23:45:00.000        0
2       3 2020-03-02 16:22:00  16:22:00.000        0
3       4 2020-04-02 18:49:00  18:49:00.000        0
4       5 2020-05-02 11:02:00  11:02:00.000        0
```